# C# resource file code generate for string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, msbuild

Here is the resource file in aspnetcore repo.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Resources.resx

The usage of it is in:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityErrorDescriber.cs

I wanna know how it generates the `Resource` class, to have the methods like `Resources.FormatInvalidUserName(userName)`. Which is especially useful when formatting string.

The default behavior of code generation in visual studio 2022 does not generate method like above. It will only generate properties. I have to call `string.Format` to format the string.

A clue is the custom tool of aspnetcore's is `MSBuild:_GenerateResxSource` while mine is `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

Please tell me how to generate code like aspnetcore repo.

I tried to edit the custom tool from `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` into `MSBuild:_GenerateResxSource`. But it does not work.

Comment: I was answering similar question recently here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76080384/7167572 It might bring some ideas/better understanding?

Comment: Here is a similar question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510667/how-to-convert-c-sharp-resource-file-strings-into-methods-and-not-just-propertie